# How to use Graphviz as a library in a C++ project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, graphviz

I'm trying to use Graphviz in a project in C++. I'm trying to follow [the guide](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/libguide/libguide.pdf).
The issue is when I try to write

```
#include <gvc.h>
```

I get

```
fatal error: gvc.h: No such file or directory
```

I've installed Graphviz and I can successfully run:

```
dot -Tps a.dot -o example.bmp
```

and get the desired image. I don't know what I should do to make it work with my project. It's unclear how to include that library in Eclipse or where to find the files.
One of the things I tried was to put the source code of Graphviz in my project and use

```
#include "gvc.h"
```

but I just faced other include problems within in the library code.
I've been searching for a solution for this for a while but couldn't find any.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to tell the compiler where the include file is located.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How can I know where this include file is located? I tried to search for it but can't find it(After installing Graphviz.)

Comment: You need to install the graphviz *development* package.

Comment: would you like to post an answer so I can upvote and accept or shall I write one?